# Spark Twitter Streaming exception : (org.apache.spark.Logging) classnotfound

Tags: maven, twitter, apache-spark

I am trying Spark Twitter Streaming example with Scala using Maven but I am getting below error when I run it:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging

Below are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version> 
</dependency>
```

I know that the `Logging` has been moved to `org.apache.spark.internal.Logging` but I don't know if it is the reason , I already tried to change the version of dependencies to the latest one but with no luck.

Comment: have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**TLDR;**

Class `org.apache.spark.Logging` is available in Spark version [`1.5.2`](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-1-5-2.html) or lower (though I didn't test on all lower versions) but is not available in versions higher than the same.

---

It all comes down to using *incompatible* version of [`Apache Spark`](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html):

#### 1. Let's try to `import org.apache.spark.Logging` on [`Spark 2.0.0`](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html):

> ```
> user@ubuntu:~$ /opt/spark/bin/spark-shell
> Welcome to
>   ____              __
>  / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
> _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
> /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.0.0
>    /_/      
> Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101)
> scala> import org.apache.spark.Logging
> <console>:23: error: object Logging is not a member of package org.apache.spark
> import org.apache.spark.Logging
>           ^
> ```

#### Class `org.apache.spark.Logging` is not found.

---

#### 2. Let's try to `import org.apache.spark.Logging` on [`Spark 1.6.2`](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-1-6-2.html):

*(same as above i.e. Class org.apache.spark.Logging is **not** found.)*

---

#### 3. Let's try to `import org.apache.spark.Logging` on [`Spark 1.5.2`](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-1-5-2.html):

> ```
> user@ubuntu:~$ /opt/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell
> Welcome to
>       ____              __
>      / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
>     _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
>    /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.5.2
>       /_/
> Using Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101)
> scala> import org.apache.spark.Logging
> import org.apache.spark.Logging
> ```

#### YES! It is available and successfully imported

As you can see that `org.apache.spark.Logging` which is required by the [Spark-Streaming-Twitter](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-twitter_2.11/1.6.2), is available in Spark version [1.5.2](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-1-5-2.html) or lower, so I would recommend you to use `1.5.2` or a lower version of spark.

Hence, you should replace your maven dependencies with followings:
(Assuming that you are using `Scala 2.11.x`)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that the `artifactId`: `2.11` refers to `scala` version and `version`: `1.5.2` or `1.6.2` refers to the library (spark-core or spark-streaming-twitter) version.

Comment: No way to do this without downgrading Apache Spark version.

Comment: I changed to <groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId> and it works, perfectly works. I don't think downgrading spark is the way forward.

Comment: @ypriverol yes. What you did is the right thing. You are welcome to edit my answer or I will do it soon.

Answer (score 10):

Good news! There is [another dependency](http://bahir.apache.org/docs/spark/2.0.0/spark-streaming-twitter/) that solves this problem, and is compatible with Spark 2.x.

For SBT, use this dependency:

```
"org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "2.0.0"
```

Comment: I am using below dependencies but result is same.                                 
           libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-twitter_2.11
//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.11" % "1.6.3" % "provided"
libraryDependencies+="org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "2.0.0"
//--packages "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:1.6.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.2.0"

Comment: Thank you for this hint. Worked the first time

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this exception using `spark-streaming-kafka_2.11-1.6.3.jar`, and solved it by using `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11-2.1.0.jar` instead

Comment: Worked for me !

Answer (score 2):

Without changing version, we can solve the issue.

Download spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.logging.jar from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swordsmanliu/SparkStreamingHbase/master/lib/spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.logging.jar and paste it in spark\jars folder. Include this jar path in spark-submit command . It solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @ypriverol suggested, change dependency to `org.apache.bahir`. [Apache Bahir](http://bahir.apache.org/) provides extensions to number of Apache analytical platforms including Spark.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging as a dependency and build the jar again..