# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new to Spark. I attempted to run a Spark app (.jar) on CDH 5.8.0-0 on Oracle VirtualBox 5.1.4r110228 which leveraged Spark Steaming to perform sentiment analysis on twitter. I have my twitter account created and all required (4) tokens were generated. I was blocked by the `NoClassDefFoundError` exception.

I've been googling around for a couple of days. The best advice I found so far was in the URL below but apparently my environment is still missing something.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html#ixzz4Ia99dsp0

What does it mean by a library showed up in Compile by was missing at RunTime? How can we fix this?

What is the library of Logging? I came across an article stating this Logging is subject to be deprecated. Besides that, I do see log4j in my environment.

In my CDH 5.8, I'm running these versions of software:
 Spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7 / spark-core_2.10-2.0.0
 jdk-8u101-linux-x64 / jre-bu101-linux-x64

I appended the detail of the exception at the end. Here is the procedure I performed to execute the app and some verification I did after hitting the exception:

1. Unzip twitter-streaming.zip  (the Spark app)
2. cd twitter-streaming
3. run ./sbt/sbt assembly
4. Update env.sh with your Twitter account

$ cat env.sh

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/cloudera/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7
export CONSUMER_KEY=<my_consumer_key>
export CONSUMER_SECRET=<my_consumer_secret>
export ACCESS_TOKEN=<my_twitterapp_access_token>
export ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=<my_twitterapp_access_token>
```

The submit.sh script wrapped up the spark-submit command with required credential info in env.sh:

$ cat submit.sh

```
source ./env.sh
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class "TwitterStreamingApp" --master local[*] ./target/scala-2.10/twitter-streaming-assembly-1.0.jar $CONSUMER_KEY $CONSUMER_SECRET $ACCESS_TOKEN $ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
```

The log of the assembly process:
[cloudera@quickstart twitter-streaming]$ ./sbt/sbt assembly

```
Launching sbt from sbt/sbt-launch-0.13.7.jar
[info] Loading project definition from /home/cloudera/workspace/twitter-streaming/project
[info] Set current project to twitter-streaming (in build file:/home/cloudera/workspace/twitter-streaming/)
[info] Including: twitter4j-stream-3.0.3.jar
[info] Including: twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar
[info] Including: scala-library.jar
[info] Including: unused-1.0.0.jar
[info] Including: spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.4.1.jar
[info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[info] Merging files...
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' with strategy 'first'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/maven/org.spark-project.spark/unused/pom.properties' with strategy 'first'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/maven/org.spark-project.spark/unused/pom.xml' with strategy 'first'
[warn] Merging 'log4j.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class' with strategy 'first'
[warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to 2 files
[warn] Strategy 'first' was applied to 4 files
[info] SHA-1: 69146d6fdecc2a97e346d36fafc86c2819d5bd8f
[info] Packaging /home/cloudera/workspace/twitter-streaming/target/scala-2.10/twitter-streaming-assembly-1.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 6 s, completed Aug 27, 2016 11:58:03 AM
```

Not sure exactly what it means but everything looked good when I ran Hadoop NativeCheck:

$ hadoop checknative -a

```
16/08/27 13:27:22 INFO bzip2.Bzip2Factory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-bzip2 library system-native
16/08/27 13:27:22 INFO zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
Native library checking:
hadoop:  true /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0
zlib:    true /lib64/libz.so.1
snappy:  true /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/libsnappy.so.1
lz4:     true revision:10301
bzip2:   true /lib64/libbz2.so.1
openssl: true /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so
```

Here is the console log of my exception:
$ ./submit.sh

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/08/28 20:13:23 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.0.0
16/08/28 20:13:24 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/08/28 20:13:24 WARN Utils: Your hostname, quickstart.cloudera resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface eth0)
16/08/28 20:13:24 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
16/08/28 20:13:24 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: cloudera
16/08/28 20:13:24 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: cloudera
16/08/28 20:13:24 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/08/28 20:13:24 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/08/28 20:13:24 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(cloudera); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(cloudera); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/08/28 20:13:25 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 37550.
16/08/28 20:13:25 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/08/28 20:13:25 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/08/28 20:13:25 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-37a0492e-67e3-4ad5-ac38-40448c25d523
16/08/28 20:13:25 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
16/08/28 20:13:25 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/08/28 20:13:25 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/08/28 20:13:25 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.0.2.15:4040
16/08/28 20:13:25 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/cloudera/workspace/twitter-streaming/target/scala-2.10/twitter-streaming-assembly-1.1.jar at spark://10.0.2.15:37550/jars/twitter-streaming-assembly-1.1.jar with timestamp 1472440405882
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 41264.
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 10.0.2.15:41264
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 41264)
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.0.2.15:41264 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 41264)
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 41264)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)I
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils$.createStream(TwitterUtils.scala:44)
    at TwitterStreamingApp$.main(TwitterStreamingApp.scala:42)
    at TwitterStreamingApp.main(TwitterStreamingApp.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 more
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.2.15:4040
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/08/28 20:13:26 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-5e29c3b2-74c2-4d89-970f-5be89d176b26
```

I understand my post was lengthy. Your advice or insights are highly appreciated!!

-jsung8

Comment: The error says that at runtime it could not find Logging class to load in package org.apache.spark. This class is simply missing from twitter-streaming-assembly-1.0.jar. Make sure when you build it goes into the jar. Is there any other jar created while you build this example.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39194820/2873538

Comment: @amit_kumar & Ajeets This indeed looks promising! Thank you so much for the direction and the link!! Although the advice on the "287358" post is quite clear a challenge for me is to identify the right pom.xml file to edit and also to download/configure Spark 1.6.2. I found half of a dozen of pom.xml files related to twitter-stream dir names...I'll play around and share what I found.

Comment: @jsung8 the answer [2873538](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39194820/2873538) is recently written by me, and you should note that `org.apache.spark.Logging` is present in [Spark 1.5.2](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-1-5-2.html) not the `1.6.2` which you seems to be going with.

Comment: @jsung8, can you post your pom.xml or .sbt file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Twitter Streaming exception : (org.apache.spark.Logging) classnotfound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893655/spark-twitter-streaming-exception-org-apache-spark-logging-classnotfound)

Answer (score 1):

Use: [`spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.jar`](http://book2s.com/java/jar/s/spark-core-2-11/download-spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.jar.html)

I had the same problem described by @jsung8 and tried to find the .jar suggested by @youngstephen but could not. However linking in `spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.jar` instead of `spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.logging.jar` resolved the exception in the way @youngstephen suggested.

Comment: core_2.11-1.5.2.logging.jar is needed during spark-submit command.

Answer (score 0):

org/apache/spark/Logging was removed after spark 1.5.2.

Since your spark-core version is 2.0, then the simplest solution is:

> download a single **spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.logging.jar** and put it in the **jars** directory under your spark root directory.

Anyway, It solves my problem, hope it helps.

Comment: where do you find it ? Would you have a link ?

Comment: @romainjouin : sorry, no link out there. I just discussed it with my partner.

Answer (score 0):

One reason that may cause this problem is **lib and class conflict**.
I faced this problem and solved it using some **maven exclusions**:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>log4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>log4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an old version of the Spark Twitter connector. This class from your stack trace hints at that:

```
org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils
```

Spark removed that integration in version 2.0. You're using the one from an old Spark version that references the old `Logging` class which moved to a different package in Spark 2.0.

If you want to use Spark 2.0, you'll need to use the Twitter connector from the [Bahir](http://bahir.apache.org/) project.

Answer (score 0):

Spark core version should be degraded to 1.5 due to the below error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
```

http://bahir.apache.org/docs/spark/2.0.0/spark-streaming-twitter/ provides the better solution for this. By adding the below dependency, my issue was resolved.

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```